# How to allow messages while inside cycle

Tags: c#, events, message-queue

I write application that simulates pathfinding algorithms. I can run algorithm or step it (like debugging). But when I run algorithm I am not able to draw any changes until the algorithm is done.

```
private void menu_run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    algorithm.Reset();
    while (algorithm.status == Algorithm.Status.Searching )
    {
        algorithm.MakeStep();
        if (this.speed != 0) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(this.speed);

        drawing_area.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I guess it's because I'm doing it all in one cycle and system is not able to handle new messages (events) that I trigger.

So how should I change my code to be able to redraw the changes after each iteration?

1. Should I somehow call Message Dispatcher to let him handle new messages after each iteration?
2. Should I create own messages and do all the work inside cycle using messages?
3. Or is there any more elegant way I?

Comment: As a quick answer, `Application.DoEvents` runs the message queue processing, so it might be what you want. Call it after `Invalidate`, and it should handle redrawing the drawing area. Still, a Timer component will probably be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do this.

Arguably the easiest for your situation would be to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` object on your form instead of calling `Sleep()` in an indefinite loop.

1. Add the timer to your form from the toolbox.
2. Set its `Interval` property to `this.speed`.
3. Set its `Enabled` property to `true`.
4. Subscribe to the timer's `Tick` event.

The handler would look something like this:

```
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (algorithm.Status == Algorithm.Status.Searching)
    {
        algorithm.MakeStep();
        drawing_area.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

You'll probably need to slightly rearrange your control logic (where the algorithm is started and stopped). You can use the `Enabled` property of the timer for this if it helps.

Another solution would be to create an object with a background thread which raises periodic events as the algorithm runs, and the form would subscribe to those events and redraw accordingly (don't forget to use `Invoke` on the events since they'll be coming from a non-GUI thread).

There's also `BackgroundWorker` which you could look into as a third alternative. But I think the timer will be easiest for you.